# How to put line breaks in text of an email sent using mime and smtplib in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have built a code to read from excel and send email through python. I can't figure out how to put line breaks inside the text. For example, My code sends email as "Hello Team The handler for this week of date1 to date2 is Name1. The handler for next week of date2 to date3 is Name2.".

I want the email to read as:

"Hello Team

The handler for this week of date1 to date2 is Name1.

The The handler for next week of date3 to date4 is Name2."

Dates and names are extracted from an excel spreadsheet.

```
import email.message
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from openpyxl import load_workbook

gmail_user = "someone@gmail.com"
gmail_appPassword = "password"
sent_from = ['someone@gmail.com']
to = ['anyone@gmail.com']


import datetime,xlrd
book = 
xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/shabib/Desktop/simple_excelmail.xlsx")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

a1=sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
b1=sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=1)

a1_as_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, book.datemode))
b1_as_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(b1, book.datemode))


from datetime import date
x1=date.today()

for rx in range(sh.nrows):

    text1= "Hello Team The handler for the week of: "'%s'% 
a1_as_date.date(),"to " '%s' % b1_as_date.date(),"is "'%s'% 
sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=2),"."


text1a=str(text1).strip('()').replace("'",'').replace(",",'')
print (text1a)

SUBJECT = "Weekly Rotation"
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, msg)

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_appPassword)
server.sendmail(sent_from, to, message)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you send your text in html you will have a much greater ability to edit it. I included an example of some things you can do if you use this format. The html for break is `<br>`.

```
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#html is the email body. We are gonna wrap some text around the analysis text
html=''
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <p>All,<br><br>Here is an email with some breaks"""

#this is just an example of how you can add to the text.
html+="""\     

   <br>Thanks,<br><br>
   <font color="blue">Bort Simpson</font><br>
   <font color="blue">Environmental Scientist</font><br>
   <font color="blue">Technical Analysis Section</font><br>
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

#this uses MIMEtext the create an email message
msg = MIMEText(html, 'html')
#    me = 'bcubrich@gmail.com'
me = 'your_email_address@whatever.com'
you=['recipient_1@whatever.com','recipient_2@whatever.com']

#the email has some attributes we can edit, like the subject
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ", ".join(you)   #create a string of recipients from a list

server = smtplib.SMTP('your.server', 25)
server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string()) #send message
```

Comment: I have tried that and i can send emails with html.but for this specific code I don't seem to find a way to refer excel cells in html.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
import email.message
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from openpyxl import load_workbook

gmail_user = "someone@gmail.com"
gmail_appPassword = "password"
sent_from = ['someone@gmail.com']
to = ['anyone@gmail.com']


import datetime,xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("C:/Users/shabib/Desktop/Python_Scripts/Email_List.xlsx")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

a1=sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=0)
b1=sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=1)



a1_as_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, 
book.datemode))
b1_as_date = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(b1, 
book.datemode))



from datetime import date
x1=date.today()

for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    text1="Hello  Team,"+'\r'+"The handler for the week of: "+'\r'+"(This Week) "+str(a1_as_date.date())+"  to "+str(b1_as_date.date())+" is "'%s'%sh.cell_value(rowx=0, colx=2)



SUBJECT = "Queue Managerment & Huddle Facilitator"
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(SUBJECT, text1)


server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(gmail_user, gmail_appPassword)
server.sendmail(sent_from, to, message)
server.quit()
```